# How can I invert/reverse a curve/ease function?

Tags: polynomials, inverse, bezier-curve, inverse-problems

I have a range of values that represents a curve. This in turn is applied in programming to an interface - rotatable knobs to be precise.

Let's say you have a knob that represents a value from 1-20. When the knob is turned all the way down it's at 1, all the way up it's at 20. However, when you position the knob at 50% it's ~4.5. This due to my graphical representation value is then interpolated through an easing function.

Things are fine when going from one direction, such as "knob position 50% = 4.5 **real** value".
However I cannot calculate what knob position I want to set by knowing the **real** value beforehand.

Let's look at my curve:

[image: Calculated curves]

In my scenario my control value (knobs for example) range from 0-65534.
Here we see 132 steps (x-axis) of interpolated data. The red **controlvalue** line is simply the control value. The blue line of **realvalue** is what a controlvalue at the step is converted into as a real value.

At this point I'm trying to figure out how to calculate a curve that can negate and give me the opposite of that transformation.
Using my previous example of the knob that goes from 1-20, I'd like to be able to input a value of 4.5 into a **new easing function** that in turn gives me the desired control value - 50%, or 32737 in my scenario range.

The green curve is my failed attempt by simply calculating my columns of data I have in Calc.
The equation goes like **controlvalue + (controlvalue - realvalue)**, and as you can see I'm way off my mark - the values actually goes over 100% now.

Is there a mathematical way of arriving at a "correct" inverse of my curve?

My actual equation for the realvalue curve is a polynomial trending line, it looks like this:

*f(x) = 1,00700664979392E-051x^12 - 3,7131435338088E-046x^11 + 5,95341600280796E-041x^10 - 5,44877937503095E-036x^9 + 3,14278561440411E-031x^8 - 1,1903278571858E-026x^7 + 2,99381548053501E-022x^6 - 4,9360056928568E-018x^5 + 5,2406997973793E-014x^4 - 2,68113835779245E-010x^3 + 4,67332812021518E-006x^2 + 0,1561599643x + 0,3499712063*

Comment: If you know that your function is increasing, why not find the inverse by interval halfing? That should be fast enough, or, if not, you can first find the inverse by interval halfing on some dense grid, and then represent the inverse by some interpolating function based on that!

Comment: Yeah I ended up solving it by making a high resolution table from my original function and then build an inverse from the opposite values so to say.